# android layout boxes overflow

Tags: android

I have this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/shape"
android:gravity="top" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="btnCat1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="btnCat1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="btnCat1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="btnCat1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

There are 4 groups of an image and text, but if I open it on small resolution I can see only 3 boxes. How can I set them to show on next line?

edit: it should looks like this example [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be trying to replicate the behavior of a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). You could accomplish switching from 2 to 4 columns based on the size of the view using a GridView.

Another alternative that may work for you, depending on your targeted versions, is to specify a different layout file to be used when less screen space is available (check table 2 "smallestWidth" row): [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). You would use this approach by specifying a folder such as "res/layout-sw600dp/" and putting an identically named layout file in that folder. In each of the layout files then explicitly layout your files with the number of columns desired.

If you are targeting devices that don't recognize the "sw" resource modifier, you could simulate this manually in your code by specifying a layout file to inflate by name, and simply pick a larger or smaller one based on the screen size (which is of course available to you when the app is running).

Let me know if you would like elaboration on a specific approach.

Answer (score 0):

You've set a constant width (100dp) for each element. It won't fit on the screen which has width lower then 400dp. One way to fix this is to use a horizontal scroll view.

Replace top RelativeLayout with the following.

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

If you wish to have different layout on different screens, like on your attached drawing, simply use two different layout xmls as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples).

Comment: but I don't want to scroll them, I need them to jump down

Comment: See my edited answer. They won't simply jump down. You need to have different xml for such arrangement.

Comment: It won't help me either..I will have to create a file for each resolution, it is like 10 files..

Comment: Just use two xml files. One in res/layout/main_activity.xml for devices smaller than 480dp and one in res/layout-sw480dp/main_activity.xml for devices 480dp wide and bigger.

Comment: it won't help..some boxes on some resolutions will be hidden anyway